# Genericising a repository interface

Tags: c#, interface, generic-interface

Can anyone suggest a way to genericise the following interfaces so I can have one single interface rather than one per repository.

```
public interface IClass1Repository
{
    Class1 NewEntity();
    Class1 AddOrUpdate(Class1 entity);
    Class1 GetById(int Id);
    Class1 GetByNavigation(string NavigationString);
    IQueryable<Class1> All();
}

public interface IClass2Repository
{
    Class2 NewEntity();
    Class2 AddOrUpdate(Class2 entity);
    Class2 GetById(int Id);
    Class2 GetByNavigation(string NavigationString);
    IQueryable<Class2> All();
}

public interface IClass3Repository
{
    Class3 NewEntity();
    Class3 AddOrUpdate(Class3 entity);
    Class3 GetById(int Id);
    Class3 GetByNavigation(string NavigationString);
    IQueryable<Class3> All();
}


public interface IClass4Repository
{
    Class4 NewEntity();
    Class4 AddOrUpdate(Class4 entity);
    Class4 GetById(int Id);
    Class4 GetByNavigation(string NavigationString);
    IQueryable<Class4> All();
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself yet?

Comment: @DanPuzey - I did, I'm looking for basically other peoples approaches.

Comment: Posting what you've tried already is always helpful in a question.  There's one really obvious approach to this that can't really be improved on, and chances are you already found it.

Comment: @DanPuzey - there is a method in my madness, in that by doing it this way it also creates a decent and straight "question -> answer" for anyone looking for exactly this :)  As you say, theres an obvious approach if you know it, but if you don't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T NewEntity();
    T AddOrUpdate(T entity);
    T GetById(int Id);
    T GetByNavigation(string NavigationString);
    IQueryable<T> All();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do it:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T NewEntity();
    T AddOrUpdate(T entity);
    T GetById(int Id);
    T GetByNavigation(string NavigationString);
    IQueryable<T> All();
}
```